# gitlab runner use SSH instead of http

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a self-hosted instance of gitlab, and a container in proxmox (Linux runner 5.4.203-1-pve #1 SMP PVE 5.4.203-1 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux) I'd like to use as runner.

The self-hosted instance has disabled https acces to repositories (only ssh is allowed).

My pipeline fails with

```
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /home/gitlab-runner/builds/gryU5_uD/0/path/to/repo/.git/
remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied. The provided password or token is incorrect or your account has 2FA enabled and you must use a personal access token instead of a password. See http://gitlab.company.cz/help/topics/git/troubleshooting_git#error-on-git-fetch-http-basic-access-denied
fatal: Authentication failed for 'http://gitlab.company.cz/path/to/repo.git/'
```

The runner was created following the gitlab manual (in runneers->add runner).

Now this answer [Gitlab Build Runner on Windows uses HTTP instead of SSH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36664247/gitlab-build-runner-on-windows-uses-http-instead-of-ssh) suggest I create a new user for the runner if I understand correctly (and add the ssh key to this user). I hope there is another solution.

EDIT:
-> add

```
[[runners]]
...  
  clone_url = "ssh://git@gitlab.company.cz"
...
```

to /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml, add the public key of the system as deploy key (and authorise it for the repo), create ~/.ssh/config with contents

```
Host gitlab.company.cz
  Preferredauthentications publickey
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

and I can manually clone the repo to the server. The pipeline still fails on permissions though... perhaps i am logged as root and I need to set this logged as user "gitlab-runner"? How do I achieve that?

Current pipeline output:

```
Getting source from Git repository
00:00
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/gitlab-runner/builds/gryU5_uD/0/path/to/repo/.git/
Created fresh repository.
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Edit2:
Right, so of course the deploy key is useless. What you need to do is to edit the .ssh/config for the gitlab-runner user.

Answer (score 1):

As i mentioned in the edits, the working way is to add the settings

```
Host gitlab.company.cz
  Preferredauthentications publickey
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

to the /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/config